# How get a value of id from template of another Component angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

I need to get an ID of a tag

from another Component template

```
  <li id="form" (onDragStart)="getDraggableId($event)">Form</li>
```

in typescript file(component) I have this

```
 getDraggableId(event) {
        this.gridService.setDraggabledIdGrid(event.mouseEvent.target.id);
        console.log("event  " + this.gridService.getDraggabledIdGrid());

    }
```

how can I get `event.mouseEvent.target.id`

I tried to create a service gridService to intermediate between the two components

```
@Injectable()
export class gridService {
    draggableIdGrid:string;

    constructor() {

    }
    getDraggabledIdGrid():string{
        return this.draggableIdGrid;
    }
    setDraggabledIdGrid(value){
        this.draggableIdGrid = value;
    }
}
```

but when I call the method getDraggableIdGrid I get undefuned value

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are accidentally creating two instances of your gridService service.

Ensure that only one ancestor component has `gridService` specified in its `providers` array – i.e., [one instance per component subtree](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#service-scope) –
or, make your service available [application-wide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#app-wide-dependencies).

Answer (score -1):

You can Do Like This

```
(<HTMLInputElement>event.target).id)
```